# ActiveMailer wrapped in Delayed job delivered with sidekid do not show in Sidekiq mailers queue? Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I use sidekiq as a my active_job queue

`config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq`

However, when I get failing deliveries (b/c of local exceptions, etc).

I do not see the failing, retrying jobs on any queue? How come?

```
Sidekiq::Queue.new("mailers").size 
=> 0
```

Shouldn't the failing deliveries be queued there? I do see them retrying (as I get email with the exception information).

I appreciate any insight into this. Thanks!

Comment: Configure Sidekiq web to visual check the status of queues. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring.  It give you a page where you can see Processed/Failed/Busy/Retries etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failed jobs are stored in the retry set until they are ready to try again.